# Where is the system console?

Tags: python

I just ran a python script in blender.

However it gave me an errror:

```
Python script failed, check the message in the system console.
```

[image]

I've searched online but i can't find the system console. I have two terminals open to the blender file already but it did not show any error message.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 19, with Blender 2,80

Comment: Please clarify the platform you are on (Linux, Mac, Windows) and the version of blender (I'm assuming 2.8).

Comment: @avatar It's Linux, you can see that by looking at the path and the console ("Red Hat")

Comment: The error is displayed above the line marked in red on the terminal/console (second screenshot right hand side). It can't find the key called "Cube", likely because there is no object called "Cube" in the scene.

Comment: thanks i updated my preferences

Answer (score 13):

Here, Window, Toggle System Console [image]

But if you run on linux / mac perhaps you need to see if you run Blender from terminal usually from that you going to find the error

Comment: I did not mention i was using Blender 2.80. there is no options Toggle system console under window

Comment: ah,, then you should check your terminal, based on your screenshot I can see the key error is right there, the error message that said you should see the system console probably not important in terminal because you already get the information in it compare to blender console. oh ya I remember linux and mac didn't have option to Toggle System Console, it just on windows

Comment: OMG. Why can't they just provide a button to open that instead of assuming people know what to do...

Comment: Seriously. This is no longer there in Blender 3.4. How to find toggle system console in 3.4?

Edit: On MacOS you have to run Blender from the terminal to see your system console.